# Publish Test Results task in Azure Devops

Tags: maven, junit, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am running my build and release pipeline in TFS/AZureDevopsServer-2019, below is the YAML used in azure-pipeline.yml

When the pipeline runs it does not generate Analytics

Build Pipeline
[image]

How ever as per  " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Cyaml " i have added below task in my pipeline

```
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/maven/pom.xml'
    goals: package
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    publishJUnitResults: true    
    sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit' 
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    codeCoverageToolOption: JaCoCo
```

Pipeline result

```
2021-03-30T17:11:52.9179560Z ##[warning]No test result files matching **/TEST-*.xml were found.
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message has indicated there is no test result files matching **/TEST-*.xml. You need to check whether you have a test task in your pipeline, and check the log after running the test task, to check whether the test file has been generated.

In addition, the default option uses JUnit format to publish test results. `**/TEST-*.xml` searches for all the XML files whose names start with `TEST-` in all subdirectories. If using VSTest as the **testRunner**, the **testResultsFiles** option should be changed to `**/TEST-*.trx`.

Comment: I agree with you is there can be possibility that there are no test cases present in Code it self

Answer (score 0):

If someone is working with agent deployed on Windows machine, here is a tip. I suggest not to specify `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` for the test results path. The test runner creates 'test results' files relative to current working directory. For example, if you are running junit, then you can specify `--junit-directory /reports`, the agent creates a `/reports` folder under current working directory and `.xml` file will be placed under `/reports`. On the contrary, specifying `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/reports` has some undesirable results.