# What are the downsides of using $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-tasks

In another post, it was mentioned that `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` in Azure pipelines has ill effects. I am curious what are the downsides of using this (we use these in lots of pipeline tasks for testing, downloading results and publishing).

[Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68648583/14055875) (I do not have access to make comments yet, so could not ask in that post, and did not want to derail that discussion.)

Comment: Not sure. These are advantages to using the `Build.BinariesDirectory` or `Build.ArtefactStagingDirectory` since these are configurable with the clean settings on the job/build. Using the default working directory doesn't have such an advantage. Another reason could be because it is not an explicit folder. Looking at the workflow, can you tell exactly were the file will drop?

Comment: I have not had problems with files dropping.  I was hoping to understand any limitations so I know what to watch for.  I do have some issues with files being really large, so I was curious when this working directory clears it files to ensure it is not retaining files from prior pipelines or tasks within the same pipeline.

Comment: Yeah, the Build Definition configuration givens what will be deleted.